# Converting long to float in C

Tags: c, cuda, floating-point

i'm having problems with large float numbers.
I'm taking the l2-norm of some vectors and having problems when working with large point values.
For example, consider vec as a vector:

```
float vec[] = { 10001.000000, 10002.000000, 10000.000000, 10003.000000,
        10003.000000, 10002.000000, 10003.000000 }; 
float sumzz = 0;
for (int i = 0; i < 7; i++) { 
     sumzz += pow(vec[i], 2);
   }
```

The output is '700280064', and it's wrong because the correct value is '700280036'.

So i tryed some stuff and i found that when i cast some large value to float it loses precision.
Another example:

```
long num = 5502160332;
printf("%ld\n", num);
printf("%f\n", (float) num);
```

The output for the first print is clearly 5502160332, while the second is 5502160384.
Am i doing something wrong?
Is there a solution about this?

EDIT: as I mentioned in a comment, the problem is that i should use as less double values as it's possibile, because i'm working with CUDA and except for Tesla or high-end Quadro cards, double values have 1/32 efficiency compared to `float` or other types.

Comment: Just fyi, `%f` in `printf` expects a `double`, which, whether you knew it or not, is what you got after variadic argument promotion, but it's quantized first via your float cast. Try a cast to full double from inception in your test, eg. `printf("%f\n", (double) num);`. The results should be closer to your expectations.

Comment: 7 significant decimal digits is about as good as it gets with `float.` Please use `double` for floating point except when there is very good reason not to. Please also read [Is floating point math broken?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/588004/is-floating-point-math-broken) and [Why Are Floating Point Numbers Inaccurate?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21895756/why-are-floating-point-numbers-inaccurate) In floating point arithmetic there is a trade-off between *range* and *precision*.

Comment: Yes, i know that all this stuff works with double values, the problem is i can't use those because i'm working with CUDA and except you have a Tesla you can't handle double values efficiently.

Comment: The most recent GPUs, such as the GTX 280s in barracuda04 and barracuda10, do support double-precision. However, by default the CUDA compiler does not use double-precision arithmetic.

Comment: Yes, but you have 1/32 of Gflops using 'double' values.

Comment: Why do you need floating point at all? You don't need `pow` to square a value.

Comment: Because i'm using CUBLAS and it works with float values.

Comment: What is the consequence of the inaccuracy?

Comment: Well, the first step is to get the l2-norm of a set of vectors. Those norms are fed to some Matrix-Matrix multiplications with CUBLAS, and the resulting matrices have a small percentage of the values completely wrong (NaN or zeros where they cannot be zero). I tried some stuff and then i found the problem was that l2-norm for large values vectors was simply wrong.

Comment: Can't you do that part outside of Cuda?

Comment: Nope, that's the core of the application. Speedup from using CUDA is huge.

Comment: What's wrong with `pow(vec[i], 2)` -> `vec[i] * vec[i]`? This is probably even faster, but the accuracy will probably be the same...

Comment: @Jabberwocky The accuracy will quite possibly be *better*, because now the compiler can optimize the accumulation using FMA (fused multiply-add).

Comment: What range of values does your program have to work with and how many such values are you at most going to accumulate? It's pointless to talk and worry about working with larger precision without first knowing why the smaller precision is not sufficient and knowing that the larger precision will be sufficient…

Comment: What does your *actual* CUDA code look like? How do you *actually* perform the accumulation in CUDA? I don't see any parallelization in the example code above. If you do not parallelize, you will almost certainly be better off not running this on the GPU at all…

Comment: That is not the CUDA code, it was an example.

Answer (score 1):

If you insist on using floats you have no choice than to accept the limited accuracy.

But since the limited accuracy makes your program fail giving NaN and 0 entries in your later matrix there is simply nothing to do but use double. And even that has limits, they just are a bit larger.

In this case your choice is 1/32 the speed or no result at all I'm afraid. Or look for a different algorithm to construct your matrix that's less suseptible to inaccuracies.

PS: You can keep your vector in floats, then cast to double to compute the matrix and cast that back to float. So anything before and after the accuracy critical step can remain fast.

Comment: Well, yeah, that's all. In fact i tried to use cublasDgemm (M-M multiplication with 'double' values) instead of cublasSgemm (the same but with 'float' values) and the results are quite good. I lose between 10 and 20% of speedup, but it's still huge compared to CPU only code, so i think CUBLAS checks data passed to it and doesn't work with 'double' if is not strictly necessary.

Comment: " so i think CUBLAS checks data passed to it and doesn't work with 'double' if is not strictly necessary."  Nothing like that happens.  If you call `cublasDgemm`, I assure you the calculations are carried out using FP64 arithmetic.  It's possible that this particular gemm call is not a major performance limiter in your code, due to other aspects of your code (other work being done).

Comment: I tested only the CUBLAS part of the program using double vs using float and the results are similar. Using double i lose nearly 30-50% in performance. I can't explain the reasons about that performance.